# Creating an array by joining all the nested array items with parent element

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

### Need a Better Solution using Pure Functions in Ramda

I have a typical nested loops function which reads in each step a nested array for loops over each nested array element then again Nested Array. And also new to functional Programming.

But I think we can solve it much in better way using pure functional programming in Ramda.

```
function test( p, {packages} ) {
  let res = []

  for (package of packages) {
    const packageResult = Object.assign({}, p, getPermitives(package))
    const { programs } = package;
    for (schedule of programs ) {
        const scheduleResult = Object.assign({}, packageResult, getPermitives(schedule))
        const { boards } = schedule;
        
        for (board of boards) {
            const boardResult =  Object.assign({}, scheduleResult, getPermitives(board))
            const { groups } = board;
            
            for (group of groups ) {
              res.push(Object.assign({}, boardResult, getPermitives(group), { Services: group.Services }))
            }
        }
    }
  }
  return res
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @CalebGeorge: I guess it's "how to solve it in a better way using pure functional programming in Ramda"?

Comment: You should edit your post to make it more clear, otherwise it will probably be closed.

Comment: It would help if you added some sample input data, the expected response, and at least a sketch of `getPermitives`.